# The sum of a range using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wish to execute a program with output as :

```
console.log(range(1, 10));  
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  
console.log(range(5, 2, -1));  
// → [5, 4, 3, 2]  
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));  
// → 55
```

I am getting an error for array.length.Please find the code below:

```
var array = [];

function range (arr){  
    var lower = Math.min(arr[0],arr[1]);    
    var upper = Math.max(arr[0],arr[1]);  

    for (var i=lower;i<=upper;i++){  
        array.push(i);  
    }  
}  

function sum(array){  
    for(var i=0;i < array.length;i++){  
        var total = total+array[i];  
    }  
}  

console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

I am at begineers level, please do help.
Thanks.

Comment: dude while calling your range function pass the arguments as range([1,10])

Comment: Should the `range(5, 2, -1)`  ==> `[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1.) You aren't returning anything in your `range` function. You need to return the filled array.

2.) You aren't passing the array correctly in the `sum` function call.

3.) You aren't returning anything in your `sum` function call.

**Without returning any values, you aren't letting your code blocks work with eachother**

```
var array = [];

function range (arr){  
    var lower = Math.min(arr[0],arr[1]);    
    var upper = Math.max(arr[0],arr[1]);  

    for (var i=lower;i<=upper;i++){  
        array.push(i);  
    }
    return array; // return the array to be used in the sum function
}  

function sum(array){  
    var total = 0; // need to create a variable outside the loop scope
    for(var i in array){  
       total = total+array[i];  
    }
    return total;
}  

console.log(sum(range([1,10]))); // pass the array correctly
```

Note that you need to set the `total` variable outside the scope of the `for-loop` within the `sum` function. That way you can return the final value. Otherwise, it would return `undefined`.

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udyhb95a/

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to pass an array when calling the range function you defined `range([1, 10])`
2. You need to rewrite your sum function

As a side note, there are more efficient ways to compute the sum of a range of elements without iterating on them.

```
function sum_of_range(start, end) {
    return end * (end + 1) / 2 - start * (start + 1) / 2;
}
```

Edit:

Here is a working sum function

```
function sum(array) {
    var accumulator = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
        accumulator += array[i];
    return accumulator;
}
```

Comment: How can I execute second example through this, please can you explain ....console.log(range(5, 2, -1));  
// → [5, 4, 3, 2]

Comment: The `sum_of_range` function is missing some parentheses and does not need the last `/ 2`. Should read:
```function sum_of_range(start, end) {
  return end * (end + 1) / ((2 - start) * (start + 1))
}
```

Comment: That said, here is how I would write it `function sumOfRange(start, end) {
  let average = (start + end) / 2;
  let numberOfTerms = (end - start)/ 1 + 1;
  return average * numberOfTerms;
}` 
Good discussion [here](https://gmatclub.com/forum/sum-of-n-positive-integers-formula-for-consecutive-integers-163301.html).

Comment: Also probably worth mentioning that even with the adjustments above `sum_of_range` will only work for sequences starting from 1, whereas `sumOfRange` does not have that limitation and will correctly tally `3,10` for example.

Comment: @rdela Both versions will work and are not limited to ranges starting by 1

Answer (score 2):

Here you declare a function with one parameter as an **array**

```
function range (arr){ 
      ...
```

But here you call a function with two arguments as **numbers**

```
console.log(range(1, 10));
```

Use this call function

```
console.log(range([1, 10]));
```

And **don't** use `for..in` for arrays

```
for(var i in array){ it doesn't work as you expect
```

Use `forEach` function or plan `for` loop

Also you have some error in `sum` function

See working example below:

```js
function range(arr) {
    var array = [];
    var lower = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
    var upper = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);

    for (var i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
        array.push(i);
    }
    return array;
}

function sum(array) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i  = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        total = total + array[i];
    }
    return total;
}

document.write('range ' + range([1, 10]) + '<br>');
document.write('sum ' + sum(range([1, 10])));
```

Comment: It was still showing me an undefined result, while I added a "return array" at the end of range function, it is working fine now.Thanks

Comment: @gauravsharma yes, you are using `array` as global variable. You can use that variable as local in the function and return it.

Comment: Do you want to say as global var does not need to return,because inspite of keeping it global I was not able to get answer without returning that value.

Comment: @gauravsharma '*global var does not need to return*' yes, you can use that global variable in other function, I've edited the answer and made the `array` variable local and now it returns from a function. It's better for your case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify `sum` & `range` function

```
function range (){
    var array = []; 
    var lower = Math.min.apply(null, arguments);    
    var upper = Math.max.apply(null, arguments);    

    for (var i=lower;i<=upper;i++){  
        array.push(i);  
    }
    return array;  
} 

function sum(array){  
    return  array.reduce((x,y)=>x+y,0);
} 

console.log(range(1, 10)); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
console.log(range(5, 2, -1)); //if we are considering min & max from params
// [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
// 55
```

Comment: The use of `reduce` is elagant, I would do it the same way. But for a newbie this might not be the simplest function to comprehend

Comment: Yea, but they will get glimpse of future ..;)

Comment: cool, this is good answer, it shows the use of javascript arrays(reduce method).Thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dear check it now.

```
                var array = [];

                function range(arr, arr1) {
                    var lower = Math.min(arr);
                    var upper = Math.max(arr1);
                    for (var i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
                        array.push(i);
                    }
                }

                function sum() {
                    var total = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        total = total + array[i];
                    }
                    return total;
                }
                console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer to the problem at the end of the data structures chapter within Eloquent JavaScript

```
function range(start, end, step) {
  let arr = []; //declare an empty array
  var step = step || 1;//tests to see if step was supplied, otherwise it's 1
  if(start < end) 
  {
    for(let i = start; i <= end; i += step)
    {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    for(let i = start; i >= end; i += step)
    {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
function sum(array) {
  let total = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
  { 
    total += array[i];
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(range(1, 10));
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
console.log(range(5, 2, -1));
// → [5, 4, 3, 2]
console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
// → 55
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution takes into account of entering a step that isn't expected to be positive/negative, i.e range from 1 to 5, we would expect step to be positive, but if the user somehow entered a negative step then an empty array would occur.

The browser actually hangs for the opposite, if the array is expected to decrease, but the step sizes are > 0.

```
'use strict';

function range(start, end, step = 1){
    let output = [];

    if (start > end){
        // Sanity check, all steps if expected to go down should be negative
        if (step > 0){
            step = -step;
        }

        for (;start >= end; start += step){
            console.log(start);
            output.push(start);
        }
    }
    else{
        // Likewise, as all steps should be positive
        if (step < 0){
            step = -step;
        }

        for (;start <= end; start += step){
            output.push(start);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

function sum(arr){
    let output = 0;
    for (let i of arr){
        output += i;
    }
    return output;
}

console.log(range(1, 5, 1));
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(range(5, 1, -1));
// → [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

// Notice this one step is a positive, but this is handled (original solution returned empty array)
console.log(range(5, 1, 1));
// → [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
// → 55
```

An improvement onto this is to use the reduce function for an array to sum instead of a for loop, i.e:

```
function sum(array){  
    return array.reduce((x,y)=>x+y,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people finding this later on as I did, here is a way to write the `range` function so you can pass the input as written in the original question:

`console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));`

…and a cleaned up `sum` function similar to the one in [A. Sharma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36718580):

```js
function range(lower, upper) {
  let array = []
  for (let i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}

function sum(array) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i in array) {
    total = total + array[i];
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

Also worth mentioning:

- The use of `reduce` in [JagsSparrow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36718281), which is elegant, while not entirely obvious and newcomer friendly as [Mathias Vonende pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718158/the-sum-of-a-range-using-javascript/36718580#comment61024298_36718281).
- Negative step tolerant versions in answers from [Jimmy Wei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54268657) and [user3225968](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50589408).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I've got

```
function range(x,y){
    var arr = [];
    for(x;x<=y;x++){
        arr.push(x);
    };
    return arr;
};

function sum(array){
    return array.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0);
};

console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is quite late but I am learning these things now and want to share my solution. I have not seen this solution provided for the specific question "Sum of a range in Javascript" so I wanted to share it. What I have done here is made use of the pop method for the array which allowed me not to specifically pass an array argument to the range function but to provide a solution to the argument in the way it was originally presented in the question.

```
var result = [];
var counter = 0;
function range(start, end) {
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    result.push(i);
  }
  return result;
}

function sum(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      counter += result.pop(i);
    }
    return counter;
}

console.log(range(1, 10));
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
// → 55
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished very easily and efficiently without any globally scoped vars.

It's not clear in the original question what behavior should be applied to the `-1` argument. It seems to be an indicator to reverse the range. In the below example, I've used a boolean to check this argument. A value of `-1` would actually be the same as not providing a third argument. To reverse the range, pass in any [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value.

```
function range(from, to, reverse) {
  // Make sure our inputs are actually numbers
  if (Number(from) != from || Number(to) != to) {
    throw new TypeError("range() expects a Number as both it's first and second argument");
  }

  let o = []; // initialize our output array
  
  // get the lowest value argument as our starting index
  let i = Math.min(from, to);
  
  // get the highest value argument as our ending index
  let x = Math.max(from, to); 

  // push i onto our output array and then increment until i == x
  while (i <= x) { o.push(i); i++; }

  // reverse the range order if necessary
  if (reverse) { o = o.reverse(); }
  
  // return our output array
  return o;
}
```

Then we can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate through the range array and add each value (`b`) to the one before it (`a`) with the [addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) (`+=`).

```
function sum(range) {
  if (!(range instanceof Array)) {
    throw new TypeError("sum() expects an Array as it's only argument");
  } return range.reduce((a,b) => a+=b);
}
```

Testing it:

```
let a = range(1,10);
let b = range(5,2);
let c = range(5,2,true);
let d = range(3,-1);
let e = range(10,10);

console.log(a); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
console.log(b); // [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
console.log(c); // [ 5, 4, 3, 2 ]
console.log(d); // [ -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log(e); // [ 10 ]
console.log(range('test', 10)); // TypeError
console.log(range(1, 'test')); // TypeError

console.log(sum(a)); // 55
console.log(sum(b)); // 14
console.log(sum(c)); // 14
console.log(sum(d)); // 5
console.log(sum(e)); // 10
console.log(sum('test')); // TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

here my answer, I'd glad if you give me feedback about this solution.

```
let arr = [];

function range(x, y) {
for (let i = x; i <= y; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}
return arr;
}

function sum(array) {
const many = array.reduce((total, number) => {
    return total + number;
}, 0);
return many;
}

console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
```